# Unable to middle align my top row for my Excel file in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am not able to middle align my top row for my excel file using the following PowerShell Code:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
```

I have checked all the relevant posts here and this is the only code I could find, could anyone advise me on this? Thanks and really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following, perhaps.
See the [XlHAlign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlhalign?view=excel-pia) enum docs for the enum members' corresponding values.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

$xlHAlignCenter = -4108
$wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = $xlHAlignCenter
```

Comment: I just tried this out but still get the same error.

Comment: No repro. Can you create a [reprex]?